# React: Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

This is my component:

```
var booksRef = new Firebase("https://bookshelf.firebaseio.com/books");

class BookShelf extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {books: [] };
      var self = this;
      booksRef.on("value", function(snapshot){
        const newbooks = [];
        var firebaseBooks = snapshot.val();
        for(var bookId in firebaseBooks){
            newbooks.push({key: bookId, book: firebaseBooks[bookId]});
        }
        var newState = self.state;
        newState.books = newbooks;
        self.setState(newState);
      });
    }
   ...
```

When I navigate to this component for the first time, there is no problem. But when I navigate to another component and then back again to this component, I get the following warning in the console:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the  component.
```

I guess I need to do something before I dispose the component, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your question, all the code you have in the class constructor above is done before mounting its essentially: componentWillMount, so that logic is ONLY being run at that point.

Now thats fine and all, but the issue is complicated buy the asynchronous request you have with firebase. There used to be a method called isMounted that you could just run a check on but now that is deprecated, the best practices for your scenario are outlined here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Check out this blog post about another (but hackey) ways to solve the issue: http://jaketrent.com/post/set-state-in-callbacks-in-react/

scroll to the es6 part, the first bit isn't directly relevant.

**Additional**:

Check out this babel blog post: Specifically the section on Classes:
Not sure if you need it, but its good

https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't know what is causing this problem, therefore I would not know what to write.

Comment: I got to editing while you wrote this, that was a poor answer, I should have held off..please see the above. It should help clear things up!

Comment: Thanks for your helpfulness!